# Не убираются метки

Tags: html, css

[image: Не убираются метки]

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <div id="dropdown-menu" class="dropdown-menu">
    <li class="active">1. Структуры данных и алгоритмы
      <ul class="ulclasspis">
        <li><a href="#1">1.1. Понятие структур данных и алгоритмов</a> </li>
        <li><a href="#2">1.2. Информация и ее представление в памяти</a> </li>
        <li><a href="#3">  1.2.1. Природа информации</a> </li>
        <li><a href="#4">  1.2.2. Хранение информации</a> </li>
        <li><a href="#5">1.3. Классификация структур данных</a> </li>
        <li><a href="#6">1.4. Операции над структурами данных</a> </li>
        <li><a href="#7">1.5. Структурность данных и технология программирования</a> </li>
      </ul>
```

Не убираются метки. Что бы не писал, что бы не делал - все без толку.

P.S. Надо убрать те, которые находятся за Блоком (белые квадратики)

Answer (score 0):

**UPD:** В стилях к списку укажите `list-style-type: none !important;`

Comment: В том то и дело что указывал! Ничего не работает!

Comment: Кидайте HTML код списка и его стиль

Comment: [ссылка] (https://imgur.com/a/Xw13P37)

Comment: А если применить `!important`? Код надо кидать в виде текста,а не фотографии..

Comment: Я не знаю как кидать код тут

Comment: @Иван, нажмите под вопросом "Редактировать" и добавьте код.

Comment: Добавил код, посмотрите

Comment: Треугольники наверно ?

Answer (score 0):

Лично я избавлялся от этого с помощью list-style: none;

```
#dropdown-menu li {
     list-style: none;
}
```